# How to get value of query string from encoded url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, url, query-string

I have the following encoded URL string in javascript

```
var querystring = "http%3A%2F%2Fspsrv%3A1361%2FSitePages%2FCountryManagment%2Easpx%3FCountryId%3D1";
```

How can I get the value of `CountryId` from that ?

Comment: A number put instead `CountryId`?

Comment: How did you encode the URL?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to decode the URL with [decodeURIcomponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) and then use `regex` to get the parameter from URL

```
var querystring = decodeURIComponent("http%3A%2F%2Fspsrv%3A1361%2FSitePages%2FCountryManagment%2Easpx%3FCountryId%3D1");
document.getElementById("decodedURL").innerHTML = querystring;
function getParam(param, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    param = param.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + param + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ");
}
document.getElementById("parameter").innerHTML = getParam("CountryId", querystring);
```

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ypzu290q/2/)

Comment: @user6599525 - No problem. Hope you can now continue with what you want to achieve

Comment: Your solution is long while simpler way exist.

Comment: @Mohammad I know there is simpler ways, this was the way I know. So I gave my answer just the same as you did. There was no need for this comment from you. You answered and I gave an answer aswell.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you should decode url, using [`.decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) you can do it. Then you can use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to spliting URL to array or use [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to selecting specific part of URL by regex.

```js
var querystring = "http%3A%2F%2Fspsrv%3A1361%2FSitePages%2FCountryManagment%2Easpx%3FCountryId%3D1";

var result = decodeURIComponent(querystring).split("?")[1].split("=")[1];
var result2 = decodeURIComponent(querystring).match(/CountryId=([\d]+)/)[1];

console.log(result, result2);
```